# CSS list items text and icon alignment

Tags: html, css

I am creating a ul list with css properties.

```
<div class="footer" style="width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color: #00b3ee">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; ">
        <li style="float: left; border-right:1px solid #bbb;">
            <a href="#" style="display: block;color: white;text-align: center; padding: 10px 10px; text-decoration: none;">item-1 <i class="fa fa-bell"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li style="float: left; border-right:1px solid #bbb;">
            <a href="#" style="display: block;color: white;text-align: center; padding: 10px 10px; text-decoration: none;">item-1 <i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This appears like this:

[image]

But I want to appearings text and icon aligned center and   one under the other.

Answer (score 2):

Just do like this :

```
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; 
    background-color: #00b3ee;
}
.footer li{
    float: left; 
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
}
.footer li a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 10px 10px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* For the icon : */
.footer li a i{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

That should set your icon above the text in the button.

Answer (score 0):

To make the icons appear below the text you must style the `li` element to `overflow: hidden` and `i` to `display: block`, like this:

```
<div class="footer" style="width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color: #00b3ee">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; ">
        <li style="float: left; border-right:1px solid #bbb; overflow: hidden;">
            <a href="#" style="display: block;color: white;text-align: center; padding: 10px 10px; text-decoration: none;">item-1 <i class="fa fa-bell" style="display: block;"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li style="float: left; border-right:1px solid #bbb; overflow: hidden;">
            <a href="#" style="display: block;color: white;text-align: center; padding: 10px 10px; text-decoration: none;">item-1 <i class="fa fa-cog" style="display: block;"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It should be said that you'll be better off by putting all of you're styling code in a CSS stylesheet as inline styling is bad practice in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the below to respective elements:
`div`- `width=20%; height=100px;`
remove `float-left` from `li`

It works fine in chrome.